# Removing items from a JList

Tags: java, swing, jlist

here is a code , I want to change `JList` items,  but when i click on open button and `JList.removeAll()` runs , my `JList` doesn't remove items...
what is the problem?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class JListTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] j = {"item1","item2","item3"};
        final JList list = new JList(j);

        JButton open = new JButton("open");
        open.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                list.removeAll();
            }
        });

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        Container con = frame.getContentPane();
        con.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        con.add(open,BorderLayout.LINE_START);
        con.add(list,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        con.add(new JScrollPane(list));
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

if you don't believe that , please test.

Comment: Probably you want to remove all elements from its model. `list.getModel().removeAllElements()` when it is a `javax.swing.DefaultListModel<E>`.

Comment: `JList#removeAll` doesn't effect the underlying data in the `JList`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you do it is wrong. With your constructor `new JList(j)` there is only a "read- only model".

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html
`It's easy to display an array or Vector of objects, using the JList constructor that automatically builds a read-only ListModel instance for you:`

You should use a real Model for it like:

```
public class JListTest {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    DefaultListModel<String> model = new DefaultListModel<>();
    model.addElement("item1");
    model.addElement("item2");
    model.addElement("item3");
    final JList<String> list = new JList<String>(model);

    JButton open = new JButton("open");
    open.addActionListener(new ActionListener()

    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            DefaultListModel<String> model = (DefaultListModel<String>) list.getModel();
            model.removeAllElements();
        }
    });
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(400, 400);
    Container con = frame.getContentPane();
    con.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    con.add(open, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
    con.add(list, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    con.add(new JScrollPane(list));
    frame.setVisible(true);

}
```

}

Comment: By default, `JList` uses a `DefaultListModel` if you don't otherwise specify one (via `setModel` for example), so you could cast it and remove the elements from it